# Dynamicly assign argparse version number python

Tags: python, argparse

I want to add a dynamic version to my code.
I've got the following working code:

```py
import argparse

VERSION = 0.2

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PDF Generator')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s version 0.1')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

when I run the -v option, it gives me the static text (0.1)
how do I change this text so that the global variable is used instead ?

When I use this code:

```py
import argparse

VERSION = 0.2

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PDF Generator')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s version %f' %VERSION)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

it raises a TypeError: format requires a mapping

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `version='%(prog)s version {}'.format(VERSION)`

Comment: thanks, that did the trick, i cant mark your answer as solved my question though, but you get my virtual kudo's :)

Comment: Or `version='%%(prog)s version %s'%VERSION`.  The `%s` is evaluated when creating the argument.  The `%%(prog)s` becomes `%(prog)s`, which is evaluated during parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the concatenation operator of string instead of string formatting like -

```
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s version ' + str(VERSION))
```

Or as answered in the comment by Lukasz , you can use `String.format` as -

```
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s version {}'.format(VERSION))
```

`Version` is replaced at the first occurrence of `{}`